# No "Modules" item in Doxygen for Fortran

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I use Doxygen  to document Fortran code. I have one module and want to document it. The module is:

```
!> Definition of object that defines a spatial domain where the 
!! calculations will take place.
!! \author Antonio
!! \date 2018-09-13
module places
    implicit none

    ! Maximum length for character type.
    integer, parameter, private    :: MAXLEN = 20    ! Maximum length for the name of places

    !> \brief Object that defines a spatial domain where the calculations will take place.
    !> \author Antonio
    !> \date 2018-09-13
    type typePlace
        character(len=MAXLEN)               :: Name
        integer                             :: Id
        real                                :: Lons
        real                                :: Lats
    end type typePlace

end module places
```

When I run Doxygen and generate the documentation, this documentation has one problem:

The main menu has three items: "Main Page", "Data Types List" and "Files", but there is no "Modules" item.

Does anybody know where I did mistake?.

The differences between my Doxyfile and the default one are:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "Calculate values"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = /calculations/doxygen
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = YES
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = F90=Fortran \
                         F95=Fortran \
                         F03=Fortran \
                         F08=Fortran
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
INPUT                  = /calculations
FILE_PATTERNS  ...
                         *.qsf \
                         *.as \
                         *.js \
                         *.f77 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited because I have solved one of the two questins that I formerly asked, but the other one remains.

Comment: What is the version of doxygen?

Comment: Please do not use external hostings for important files. Is it really *that* large? Also, please pay attention to question titles, read [ask]. *I am new to X* is *not* a good question title. Describe your question or problem instead.

Comment: The version is: Doxyfile 1.8.5

Comment: Regarding the Doxyfile, just mention / show the values you changed compared to the original Doxyfile

Comment: Why are you using the `/` with spaces around it? the normal doxygen command is `doxygen MyDoxyfile` or when it is in a sub directory: `doxygen subdir/MyDoxyFile`. My comment  was just a reformulation of an old comment with a typo.  Difference is not necessary anymore for the current problem as the problem has been solved by updating doxygen.

Comment: You have to open a new question for this.

Comment: I have deleted my comments related to off topic questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen version 1.8.5 is from 2013, since that time a lot has changed. The current doxygen version is 1.8.14.

When using version 1.8.14 the "item" module is present (set `OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN=YES` otherwise it is shown as namespace).

Solution is to upgrade to a more recent version of doxygen.